# PHPUnit mocking global functions

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I want to mock a function with `PHPUnit`. However, the function is a global function (it is just in a file).

```
function getOwner($wsn)
{
    $handle = Config::$pdo->prepare('CALL GetWsnById(?)');
    $handle->bindValue(1, $wsn);
    $handle->execute();

    if ($handle->rowCount() == 1) {
        $wsnRow = $handle->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $wsnRow['Username'];
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

`$this->createMock` always expects a class name first before I can call the method.

Is there another way to mock the method without it being in a class?

Comment: Also, just for your own reference, a _function_ is a block of reusable code, and a _method_ if a function bound to an object. It is really just semantics, but it might help you when searching and/or talking about this.

Comment: To add to what Chris Hass mentioned, you want `How to mock global functions`... The answer is you can't... you have a poor design then...